# Webhook Test fails during jenkins Gitlab integration

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, webhooks

I am trying to integrate jenkins with Gitlab for CI such that if push event is happens then build will be triggered. I am using two things to connect. One is Gitlab acess token: I have created project specific access token and added in Jenkins global configuration. Second is SSH primary key: I have added this in my job configuration. Now when I test the webhook I get below error. Can any leads help me to fix it?

Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 500 <head resURL="/static/861bc558" data-rooturl=""

I will attach full error if needed

Comment: please post the err